# Какую синтаксическую роль выполняет глагол "поможет"?

Tags: cинтаксис

*Они пытались спасти от потопа **что Бог поможет**.*

(comentario: Мне очень хочется поставить запятую после слова *потопа*, но в задании она не стоит.)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фраза "что Бог поможет" - **составное дополнение** глагола "*спасти*".  Вопрос: спасти ***что***?  Возможные ответы:

- все свои вещи
- что удастся (спасти)
- только самое необходимое
- что Бог поможет (спасти)

(в скобках - повторение, которое опускается).

Answer (score 1):

Они пытались спасти от потопа что Бог поможет (хотя бы что-нибудь, любой предмет)

Это тема **устойчивых оборотов с  с подчинительными союзами**, которые обычно имеют значение одного слова. Устойчивые обороты не выделяются запятыми,  и их можно заменить синонимичным словом или выражением, например: Приходится брать что попало. Говорит что на ум взбредёт.